# Слова : свихнуться, помешаться, тронуться

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте. Поймав себя за распеванием песен на улице и разговором с самом собой, подумал: а каковы же значения этих слов? Свихнуться созвучно с вывих, вихрь... Я не лингвист, - это корень? что он означает? Свихнуться в значении сместить, свернуть сознание? Что это за процесс? Помешаться с чем/кем? Тронуться - это как тронуть самого себя? Какие процессы описывают эти слова и как они были образованы?

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое в Вашем обширном вопросе - это лексическое значение слов.

Все три искомых слова легко обнаружимы в толковых словарях; чтобы далеко не ходить, ограничимся Грамотой.ру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение корней нам подсказывают этимологические словари, но не все слова имеют прояснённую этимологию...

> ВИХРЬ. Общеслав. Образовано посредством суф. -р- от основы вих- (см.
>   вихлять).
>
> ВИХЛЯТЬ. Искон. Суф. производное от вихлый, образованного посредством
>   суф. -л- (ср. кислый, тухлый и т. п.) от вихать "колебать", в
>   диалектах еще известного.

"Вывих" нашёлся [у филолога с Большого Вопроса](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/981140-kakaja-etimologija-u-slov-podvoh--vyvih--viljat-.html):

> ВЫВИХ -- тоже собственно-русское слово. Здесь попроще, по-моему,
>   объяснение. От слова ВИХНУТЬ, означающего "сдвигать с места", было
>   образовано при помощи приставки ВЫ- другой глагол ВЫВИХНУТЬ, а от него
>   существительное ВЫВИХ. Вот такая цепочка образования этого слова. Да и
>   смысл совершенно понятен: ведь вывих -- это тоже какой-то сдвиг.

Что касаемо нищасного постфикса *-ся,* то у него стока многа значений, что лучше книжку [какую-нито](http://www.lingling.ru/useful/expert.php?ELEMENT_ID=1447) об том почитать; цитирую "наш" случай с "тронуть самого себя":

> ...У постфикса -ся есть и множество других значений – действие,
>   которое может происходить само по себе без участия деятеля (рваться,
>   нагреваться, сыпаться), действие, обозначающее чувство, причиной
>   которого служит кто-то другой или что-то другое (пугаться, радоваться,
>   удивляться) и другие. Возвратное значение, о котором знают все –
>   далеко не единственное значение постфикса -ся.

Шанский (не в Фасмера же забираться?):

> ТРОГАТЬ (касаться). Искон. **Надежной этимологии нет.** Наиболее
>   предпочтительным является объяснение слова как родственного общеслав.
>   търгати "рвать, дергать, терзать" (см. восторг).
>
> ВОСТОРГ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Производное от въстъргати "взрывать",
>   "срывать", преф. производного от търгати "рвать". Значение "подъем
>   радостных чувств" < "взрыв" (вверх).

Насчёт "помешаться", так это к миксеру:

> МЕСИТЬ. Общеслав. Того же корня, что лат. misceo "смешиваю", нем.
>   mischen "мешать", англ. mix "смешивать". См. миксер.