# Значение и происхождение слов: свихнуться, помешаться, тронуться

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте. Недавно задумался над значением этих слов. Свихнуться, вихрь, вывих - однокоренные? Что означает этот корень? Что означает само слово, сместиться с нормальной точки мышления? Помешаться с чем/кем?  Тронуться это как тронуть самого себя? Как произошли эти слова и какие процессы они описывают?

Comment: Вам же ответили уже. Зачем повторяете вопрос?

Comment: Так и есть, первый мой вопрос в разделе rus, на почту пришло письмо с подтверждением пароля, перешел по ссылке, подвтердил пароль, появилась надпись - тема не найдена, я решил что просрочил время подтверждения темы и создал заново.

Comment: Нет, тема живая. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420280  Плохо искали.

Comment: В таких случаях рекомендуется закрыть дубликат. Думаю, вы не будете возражать.